# How do I display the original user input into my final output after it has been run through the program?

Tags: java, user-input, storing-data

I'm working on a project that converts feet to meters. It asks the user to input feet to be converted, then converts that input to meters. My program works fine, but I want to display what the users original value was AND the converted value into something like this:

```
System.out.println(yourFirstValue + "in meters is" + yourFirstValueConverted);
```

I'm not sure how to keep that original value to use again after its been converted and I want my program to only have to ask ONCE for the feet the user wants to convert to meters.

Comment: Just save it in a variable. You can have as many variables as you need in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do something like this,

```
double yourFirstValue = 0.0; //values user given
double yourFirstValueConverted = 0.0 //converted value
```

Now you got two variables which hold's initial and final values.